# Why is my table's <th> style overshadow by the global one?

Tags: css

In main.html, I have this

```
<style type="text/css">
#hor-my-bundles
{
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 45px;
    width: 480px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: left;
}
#hor-my-bundles th
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #039;
    padding: 10px 8px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #6678b1;
}
#hor-my-bundles td
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #669;
    padding: 6px 8px;
}
#hor-my-bundles tbody tr:hover td
{
    color: #009;
}
</style>
    <table id="hor-my-bundles">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"> Name </th>
                 ...and a few more.....
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
               ...body stuff
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I have a global css enabled, which has the following:

```
table{}
th{ background-color: #BBB; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;}
td, th{ }
td{}
tr:hover{ background-color: #dfd; }
```

But I thought since I've specified my table with a different cs id, `<td>` and etc should follow those as well. Instead, my `<th>` in this case is following the global style.

Why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified a `background-color` for your `#hor-my-bundles th, #hor-my-bundles tbody tr:hover td` styles. That's all I can see that would affect the style.

It correctly takes the styles in this example http://jsfiddle.net/sN8ed/2/